# shmctl throws "cannot allocate memory" in C

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have this code:

```
#define SHMSIZE 8388606
int main()
{
    int shmid;
    void *shmPtr;
    char *shm;
    if ((shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(char) * SHMSIZE , IPC_CREAT |        0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((shmPtr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) {
       perror("shmat");
       exit(1);
    }
    shm = (char *)shmPtr;
    strncpy(shm, "0\n", 2);

    struct shmid_ds  shmid_ds;
    int rtrn = shmctl(shmid, SHM_LOCK, &shmid_ds);
    if(rtrn < 0) {
        perror("shmctl");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Nailed it\n" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running it, I get the error:

> shmctl: Cannot allocate memory

Defining smaller value for SHMSIZE fixes the error, but what I found weird is that this error is thrown in the "shmctl" part. My reasoning tells me that this error is supposed to be thrown in the "shmget" part.

How does this code runs successfully through the shmget() call? Did I miss something important?

Comment: I recommend you [read the `shmctl` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmctl.2.html), and what it says about the `ENOMEM` error.

Comment: `struct shmid_ds  shmid_ds;` is not initialised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this, It may help you to solve your problem:

```
   The caller can prevent or allow swapping of a shared memory segment
   with the following cmd values:

   SHM_LOCK (Linux-specific)
             Prevent swapping of the shared memory segment.  The caller
             must fault in any pages that are required to be present
             after locking is enabled.  If a segment has been locked,
             then the (nonstandard) SHM_LOCKED flag of the shm_perm.mode
             field in the associated data structure retrieved by
             IPC_STAT will be set.

   SHM_UNLOCK (Linux-specific)
             Unlock the segment, allowing it to be swapped out.

   In kernels before 2.6.10, only a privileged process could employ
   SHM_LOCK and SHM_UNLOCK.  Since kernel 2.6.10, an unprivileged
   process can employ these operations if its effective UID matches the
   owner or creator UID of the segment, and (for SHM_LOCK) the amount of
   memory to be locked falls within the RLIMIT_MEMLOCK resource limit
   (see setrlimit(2)).
```

Try this:

> int rtrn = shmctl(shmid, IPC_STAT, &shmid_ds);